# How to create many objects from a character vector: the object names as the vector element names, and the object values as the vector element values

Tags: r, vector, assign

Imagine we have:

```
X <- 1:4
names(X) <- c("A" ,"B" , "C", "D")
```

I would like to create four objects in the global environment, A, B, C, D, each with the corresponding values 1, 2, 3, 4. I assume the solution involves the assign and apply functions but hope someone here could come up with something nicer than I could.

(Context: I'd like to create a kind of pseudo make file, based around a named character vector in which the names are the names of the objects I'd like to create, and the values are the names and locations of csv files I'd like to populate each object with... The toy example above is a step towards this.)

Comment: Better put everything in a list. Some version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/1412059)  should be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I agree in general about lists but think this might be an exception. I want to create a semi makefile script that will fetch and prepare a number of dataframes for further analysis, but of course I won't know exactly how many datasets will be used in the end, so don't want the names and number of dataframes to be hardcoded at the start.

Comment: Well, usually you put all files in one directory and then use `lapply` with `list.files` and `read.csv`. I don't see how your use case is an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list2env` :

```
list2env(as.list(X),.GlobalEnv)
```

Of course as mentioned in the comment, it is not a good practice to use separated global variables and clutter the global environment . The R way , is to keep your variables in a list  or a vector and use `xxapply` family functions to manipulate each vector element.

Comment: +1 but we should mention that the global environment should not be cluttered.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
for(i in seq_along(x)){
     assign(names(x)[i],x[i])
}
```